# Broadcast Receiver for ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON without Manifest Intent filter not working

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, intentfilter

For my Android audio player app I set up a BroadcastReceiver class to get media button events. It receives "android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION" broadcasts but no "Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON" broadcasts.

With the Intent filter in the Manifest file it works. But I don't want to use the Manifest entry, because the app should only react on button presses when it is running. I also read that Manifest is not needed here.

The Intent filter is set dynamically in the Activity:

```
public static myButtonReceiver receiver = new myButtonReceiver();

private void registerBroadcastReceiver() {
    IntentFilter mediaFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON);
    mediaFilter.addAction("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION");
    mediaFilter.addAction("android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON");
    mediaFilter.setPriority(2147483647);
    registerReceiver(receiver, mediaFilter);
}
```

The ButtonReceiver will only be called on Volume change events, not with MEDIA BUTTON action:

```
public class myButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if ((intent.getAction().equals("android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION")) {
        // Volume button things...
        abortBroadcast();
        return;
    }
    KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
    if (event == null)
        return;
    if (event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
        if ((event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK)
        ||  (event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE)
        ||  (event.getKeyCode() == 127)) { // 127 = KEYCODE_MEDIA_PAUSE
            // Stop/Play things...
        }
        abortBroadcast();
        }
    }
}
```

I also tried with AudioManager, which ist also not working.

```
audio_manager = (AudioManager)getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio_manager.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver
    (new ComponentName(this,myButtonReceiver.class));
```

The app is written for old Android 2.2 to keep compatibility. But as Volume change works, I don't unterstand why Media button don't. Thanks for any help.

Comment: "I also read that Manifest is not needed here." - Are you sure about that? I did something with the Media Buttons once, and it was a while ago, but I'm pretty sure it requires the manifest entry.

Comment: No, am not. But when I use the manifest way, the app even starts on pressing the headset button when it was not running. And receiving volume changed action works without a manifest entry.